# Send Command to http server

Tags: java, http, server, client, send

Good evening, I got this Server here

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    int theValue = atomicInteger.get(); 
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
    String response = String.format("Besuche: %d%n", atomicInteger.addAndGet(1));
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());
        os.close();
    }
}


}
```

Its counting every visit i do on the website http://localhost:8000/test
Now i have a client which shows me the content of the server in my console.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL test = new URL("http://localhost:8000/test");
    URLConnection connect = test.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
}
```

I want the client to send the server a command which resets the counter on the server. I could just find this [here](http://www.careerbless.com/samplecodes/java/beginners/socket/SocketBasic1.php) but i dont know how to implement this in my case. I hope someone can explain me what i can do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've given, `MyHandler`'s method `handle` handles the requests for the `/test` path. So first thing you should decide upon is if you want to receive the *reset* command on the same path or on a different one?

If you want to handle on the same path, then you need to modify the `MyHandler` to differentiate between the request to increase the number stored in `atomicInteger` - let's call that `GET` command, and the request to reset the counter - let's call that `POST` command. See what we have done? We have used two [HTTP request methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to differentiate between the two commands. Now you want to change the `MyHandler` to implement that. On the `handle` method you receive [`HttpExchange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html) object in the `t` parameter that has the [`getRequestMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#getRequestMethod--) method. So the code would look something like:

```
@Override
public void handle(final HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
    final String response;

    final String requestMethod = t.getRequestMethod();
    if ("GET".equals(requestMethod)) {
        response = String.format("Besuche: %d%n", atomicInteger.addAndGet(1));
    }
    else if ("POST".equals(requestMethod)) {
        atomicInteger.set(0);

        response = "Reset to 0";
    }
    else {
        throw new IOException("Unsupported method");
    }

    t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
    final OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
}
```

If you want to handle on a different path, let's say on `/reset`, you need to register another handler for that path i the `main` method add:

```
server.createContext("/reset", new ResetHandler());
```

Now in that handler and in the existing handler you need to share the same state of the program - the same `AtomicInteger` reference. This is best accomplished by creating the `AtomicInteger` in the `main` method and passing it to the two handlers using the handler's constructor. This would look something like:

```
static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private final AtomicInteger counter;

    public MyHandler(final AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        // ... same code, only reference the counter
    }
}

static class ResetHandler implements HttpHandler {
    private final AtomicInteger counter;

    public ResetHandler(final AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        counter.set(0);

        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 2);
        exchange.getResponseBody().write("OK".getBytes());
    }
}
```

And in the `main` method:

```
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler(counter));
server.createContext("/reset", new ResetHandler(counter));
```

There are other possibilities like using HTTP parameters or different methods, but this should get you started.

*Edited to add:*
In the client you can specify the request method like this:

```
final URL test = new URL("http://localhost:8000/test");
final HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) test.openConnection();
connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: I tried to handle it on the same path but how will it reset? If i refresh it still counts up but doesnt reset anything. How do i POST something than?

Comment: @SebastianKawa see the edit at the bottom of the answer

Comment: awesome its working. Thanks man. I just got the problem that if i Reset it to 0 it starts counting from 2. I´ll try to find out why. If you got any tips you are welcome.

Comment: @SebastianKawa sure, but create another question with code you're struggling with

Comment: I found it out, Thanks for you efford